# ISTIO Service mesh setup on AKS Traffic Management

Tags: service, istio, mesh

I am facing issue in setup service mesh on my AKS cluster, AKS connected to APIM, service exposed to Public Via APIM, how to configure YAML for this specific scenario i am not able find any article related to this, traffic management

need support for creating traffic management YAMLs'